# About Homework 4 - Getting PayParams through binding

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, monad

This question is in the context of the homework for Lecture 4.
What is wrong with the following reasoning?

We know that `payContract` is type `m ()`, where `m` stands for the monad `Contract () PaySchema Text`.  Therefore

```
payContract = do                                                                
    pp <- awaitPromise $ endpoint @"pay" return
```

must bind `()` to the variable `pp`.  Hence pp does not contain information about PayParams.

Obviously my argument is wrong, because `ppLovelace pp` does give you the payment amount.  But where exactly is the error in my logic?

Comment: Could you resolve your question with any of the answers here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Obviously my argument is wrong, because ppLovelace pp does give you the payment amount.

Yes the argument is wrong because first of all the endpoint @"pay" return means it returns the value of @"pay" immediately so the side-effect which would be () is not reached. Also the function has a final call awaitPromise which returns a new monad with a different return value. Again the () is not seen by awaitPromise.

I hope I explained myself ok.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the full **payContract** in **Homework.hs**.

```
payContract :: Contract () PaySchema Text ()
payContract = do
    pp <- awaitPromise $ endpoint @"pay" return
    let tx = mustPayToPubKey (ppRecipient pp) $ lovelaceValueOf $ ppLovelace pp
    void $ submitTx tx
    payContract
```

where  `pp <- awaitPromise $ endpoint @"pay" return`  is an intermediate computation which doesn't determine the type result of the function **payContract**. The type result of the function is given by the last expression in the function: `payContract`.

The type of `awaitPromise $ endpoint @"pay" return` is **Contract () PaySchema PayParams**. Therefore, pp is **PayParams**. But again, it's an intermediate computation.